# How do I get rid of this popup in Android Studio? Image attached

Tags: android, android-studio, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to get rid of a popup (I don't know what type of popup this is) in Android Studio that so far cannot be removed by unchecking all the checkboxes that have to do with code completion and popups (documentaion popup).

I understand what the message is the popup is trying to warn me of, I just want to get rid of it completely as it gets right in my way, how can I do this? Is it possible to disable all hover actions in Android Studio or all of the JetBrains Suite?

Thanks.

[image: How to disable whatever this is]

Comment: share some of your code here where  you are getting this .it seems code error

Comment: Hi @Danialclarc Yes it is a code error but I just want to disable the popup, I don't mind the red lines denoting an error I'm just concerned about the popup

Comment: I managed to reproduce this popup. Unfortunately it is not related to an inspection you could disable. So I don't see a solution...

Comment: @Benoit alright, thanks anyway.